# Puppeteer invalid selector

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, puppeteer, headless-browser

I'm trying to fill a form with Puppeteer on a webpage, the input has an id and I'm using it as a selector.

The ID is :

```
#loginPage:SiteTemplate:formulaire:login-field
```

When I get the selector from chrome it gives me that :

```
#loginPage\3a SiteTemplate\3a formulaire\3a login-field
```

And wether I put the first or the second option in Puppeteer it spits me out this error :

```
Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#loginPage:SiteTemplate:formulaire:login-field' is not a valid selector.
```

Here is the code if needed :

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('XXX');
    await page.click(GOTO_LOGIN_BUTTON_SELECTOR)
    await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'});
    await page.waitFor(EMAIL_SELECTOR); // here
    await page.focus(EMAIL_SELECTOR);
    await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.email);
    await page.focus(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
    await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.password);

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

One option, for an ID like that, is to do as follows:

```
const EMAIL_SELECTOR = '[id="loginPage:SiteTemplate:formulaire:login-field"]';
```

Or, if that doesn't work, split it up as follows to work around the use of the `:`:

```
const EMAIL_SELECTOR = '[id*="loginPage"][id*="SiteTemplate"][id*="formulaire"][id*="login-field"]';
```

Hopefully one (or both) of those will help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I would drop the line `await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'});`

And replace `await page.waitFor(EMAIL_SELECTOR); // here`

with `await page.waitForSelector(EMAIL_SELECTOR);`

And test to see if just using #login-field or other `#loginPage > SiteTemplate > formulaire > login-field`

I could be wrong as I'm still working this out too.